# File drag and drop works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I am trying drag and drop from outside `frame` to inside `frame`. Draggable element is located outside `iframe`, but container which is located in `iframe`. I have already posted my problem here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497662/drag-and-drop-from-outside-frame-to-inside-frame-in-selenium

I have tried `dragAndDrop` action and `ClickAndHold` + `moveToElement`. Also with `X,Y` location of element. Nothing worked in Chrome and Firefox. No error though. But it works only in IE. This is weird. I am using `selenium-java-2.53.0` with eclipse. Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Would you present your script here? Make it easy for users to help you!!